# JavaScript error with do while loop

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Trying to create a script that asks a user for a range of positive inputs and ends when a negative input is introduced. Then prints the sum and average of the inputs in an alert. Any idea why I'm getting an error on my if statement?

```
var value;
var sum = 0;
var HTMLout;
var i = 0;

do {

    if(isNaN(value) {
        alert("Enter a positive integer");
    } else {
        value = parseInt(prompt("Enter a positive integer", "Enter a negative integer to quit"));
        sum += value;
        i++;
    }

} while(value != -1);

HTMLout += alert("The sum of these numbers is " + sum);
HTMLout += alert("The average of these numbers is " + sum/i);
```

Comment: What kind of an error? Please include that info, too, it will help with identifying  the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a closing bracket:

```
if(isNaN(value)
```

should be

```
if(isNaN(value))
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax Error.

Change `if(isNaN(value)` to `if(isNaN(value))`

------------------------------------------------------------^ `Missing Parenthesis`

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax error
You forgot to place the ending parenthesis. Change if statement to the below code

```
if(isNaN(value))
{
    alert("Enter a positive integer");
}
```